# LEFT JOIN two tables with multiple AND conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I need help getting a sql statement correctly by joining two tables.

[image]

My goal is to return the number of purchases between certain purchase dates for given products where `customer_id` is null. The foreign key for table `Purchases` is `prospect_id` corresponding to `id` in `Prospect`

In separate SQL statements, I will have this:

```
SELECT COUNT (id) FROM Purchases 
WHERE (purchasedate BETWEEN '5/1/18' AND '12/31/18')
AND (product = 'Scooter')

SELECT id
from Prospect
where customer_id is null
```

So, I am coming up with a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT (id)
FROM Purchases
LEFT JOIN Prospect 
ON Prospect.id = Purchases.prospect_id
AND (Purchases.purchasedate BETWEEN '5/1/18' AND '12/31/18')
AND Purchases.product = 'Scooter'
AND Prospect.customer_id is null;
```

but then I am getting ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Both answers helped me find the correct solution. Apart from not defining the table for Id , when i call COUNT, i also needed to do a RIGHT JOIN, because i needed all Prospect.customer_id that are null. LEFT JOIN was giving me incorrect results.

Comment: (Obviously) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use 1 phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: @philipxy - obviously... you were the only one that did not understand the question. The post clearly states what is the goal, as long as you don't read between the lines. And obviously, if i knew that what the query would look like (left or right join), i wouldn't have posted the question. This title is relevant to what i have posted. And obviously, this is not obvious to you, don't assume that you are the only one knowing how to google, before considering posting a question. There isn't another post where it would have solved my question. With that respect, both users below addressed my need

Comment: I understand the question enough to guess like anybody else. I am not assuming anything, I am responding to what you wrote. There's a reason why a [mcve] is required for code questions & why duplicates become faqs & it includes people not doing the helpful things in my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `count(*)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Purchases pu LEFT JOIN
     Prospect pr
     ON pr.id = pu.prospect_id AND
        pr.customer_id is null
WHERE pu.purchasedate >= '2018-05-01' AND
      pu.purchasedate < '2019-01-01' AND
      pu.product = 'Scooter';
```

I made a few changes to the query.

First, the conditions on `purchase` are in the `where` clause rather than the `on` clause.  Presumably, you actually want these to be filters.

Second, the dates use a proper format, YYYY-MM-DD.

I've also replaced the `between` with explicit comparisons.  This means that the code works even when the "date" column has a time component.

Finally, I also introduced table aliases.

Comment: up vote for suggesting COUNT (*) , date formatting and the much cleaner solution with table aliases.

Answer (score 2):

the reason for your error is that you did not define what table the "id" field you want to count is coming from.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(PURCHASES.ID) AS PURCHASE_COUNT
FROM 
Purchases 
LEFT JOIN Prospect 
ON Prospect.id = Purchases.prospect_id
AND (Purchases.purchasedate BETWEEN '5/1/18' AND '12/31/18')
AND Purchases.product = 'Scooter'
AND Prospect.customer_id is null;
```

Comment: up vote for finding my error not specifying the table with "id".